# get variable from included file?

Tags: php

I have a php file. Name is never mind.
I think you will understand. But i want to use function.

Example.php file have a variable that reserve file name.

```
<?php
 $name = "abcdfg";
?>
```

And my function is:

```
function getData($arg)
{
require_once($arg . '.php');
//return
}
```

If i write

```
<?php 
echo var_dump(getData("$name"));
?>
```

I need to get

```
"abcdfg"
```

I'm waiting your reply..

Comment: in your code, this will run ->> require_once('$x.php') , I think you should look [@DonCallisto's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283677/get-variable-from-included-file#9283730).

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't too much clear.

From the title, I cant suggest you to use `GLOBAL` scope variables.

So, declare a variable in the file that you'll include and, then, write down in the "second" file the variable as global.